# Why is there a huge space in between my two slideshows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I didn't add any br in between the two slideshows so why is there a huge space (as big as 7 line breaks) in between it?

All I know is basic html and css (which I learned on my own). I don't know anything about Javascript AT ALL. The Javascript code I have below is from w3schools which my teacher showed us.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}

var slideIndex = [1, 1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex[no] = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex[no] = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex[no] - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
/* B O D Y */

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  background-image: url(stars.gif);
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}


/* S I D E B A R */

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}


/* A B O U T  T H E  A U T H O R */

#about-the-author-heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(188, 184, 184);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(188, 184, 184);
  color: white;
}

#about-the-author-description {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#about-the-author-image {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#about-the-author-description {
  color: white;
}


/* S L I D E S H O W */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.mySlides1,
.mySlides2 {
  display: none text-align: center;
  height: 600px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mySlides1 img,
.mySlides2 img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.slideshow-title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="about-the-author">About</a>
  <a href="#">Bucket List</a>
  <a href="#">Interests</a>
  <a href="#">Education</a>
</div>


<div>
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ MENU</button>
</div>

<div id="content">

  <div id="about-the-author">
    <h1 id="about-the-author-heading">About the Author</h1>
    <img title="gf ni jeyen" id="about-the-author-image" src="author.jpg" alt="picture of the author at the beach">
    <p id="about-the-author-description"> Dana has been a student for over 14 years. She’s currently a Grade 12 honor student of her section, St. Benedict, in Malate Catholic School. Her experience in cramming and staying late at night has enabled her to finish this project. </p>
  </div>

  <h1 class="slideshow-title">Bohol Travel (2019)</h1>
  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 21</div>
      <img src="1airport.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 21</div>
      <img src="2zoocolate.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 21</div>
      <img src="3zoocolate.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 21</div>
      <img src="4zipline.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">5 / 21</div>
      <img src="5zipline.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">6 / 21</div>
      <img src="6sikatuna.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">7 / 21</div>
      <img src="7sikatuna.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">8 / 21</div>
      <img src="8dumaluan.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">9 / 21</div>
      <img src="9loboc.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">10 / 21</div>
      <img src="10loboc.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">11 / 21</div>
      <img src="11chap.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">12 / 21</div>
      <img src="12chap.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">13 / 21</div>
      <img src="13chap.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">14 / 21</div>
      <img src="14chocolate.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">15 / 21</div>
      <img src="15chocolate.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">16 / 21</div>
      <img src="16balicasag.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">17 / 21</div>
      <img src="17balicasag.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">18 / 21</div>
      <img src="18visland.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">19 / 21</div>
      <img src="19dolphin.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">20 / 21</div>
      <img src="20dolphin.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides1 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">21 / 21</div>
      <img src="21henann.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>

  <h1 class="slideshow-title">Jeyen :></h1>
  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides2">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 20</div>
      <img src="j1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 20</div>
      <img src="j2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 20</div>
      <img src="j3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 20</div>
      <img src="j4.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">5 / 20</div>
      <img src="j5.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">6 / 20</div>
      <img src="j6.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">7 / 20</div>
      <img src="j7.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">8 / 20</div>
      <img src="j8.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">9 / 20</div>
      <img src="j9.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">10 / 20</div>
      <img src="j10.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">11 / 20</div>
      <img src="j11.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">12 / 20</div>
      <img src="j12.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">13 / 20</div>
      <img src="j13.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">14 / 20</div>
      <img src="j14.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">15 / 20</div>
      <img src="j15.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">16 / 20</div>
      <img src="j16.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">17 / 20</div>
      <img src="j17.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">18 / 20</div>
      <img src="j18.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">19 / 20</div>
      <img src="j19.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides2 fade">
      <div class="numbertext">20 / 20</div>
      <img src="j20.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because there's text between your slideshows! All of your text is white on a white background, so you can't see any of the words. Highlight that empty space and you'll find the word `Jeyen :>`. To see all of the text on your page, change `.content`'s `background-color` to something like `lightgray`.

Remove the line `<h1 class = "slideshow-title">Jeyen :></h1>` and the space between your slideshows goes away.

Comment: It’s the title of my slideshow. Our teacher requires us to have it. So if I don’t remove it, I wont be able to remove the space? I can also see all the text since I have opacity for the background so it’s not entirely white.

Comment: @Dana you can keep the h1 but make it display somewhere else using css. Where do you want it to show up?

Comment: I tried to move the h1 code below the slideshow code to make the title show up under the slideshow but the space is still there. How do I make it to show up below instead?

Comment: This is the code my teacher showed us: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_multiple          It works fine there though.

Comment: I tried removing <h1 class = "slideshow-title">Jeyen :></h1> but the space is still there. Maybe the problem is with my pictures? I did try removing them one by one though to see if the problem is with the pics but it did nothing.